# How to tell if Ubuntu is using WiFi or Ethernet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I'm using Kubuntu18.04 and whenever I use Firefox with the Ethernet cable connected or without I get the same download speed. But with Falkon download speeds are 30mb/s faster and upload speeds are 10mb/s slower. Also if I turn WiFi off and try to use either web browser they don't work. So what I'm asking is how to tell if Ubuntu is using Ethernet or WiFi and if not using Ethernet how to make it use Ethernet.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell whether your computer is using wifi or ethernet to access the internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766237/how-to-tell-whether-your-computer-is-using-wifi-or-ethernet-to-access-the-intern)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu will use both your Wireless and your Ethernet at the same time. I use a program called `vnstat` for Internet traffic monitoring:

```
$ vnstat

                      rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
 wlp60s0:
       Apr '18     20.83 GiB  /    1.55 GiB  /   22.38 GiB
       May '18      4.33 GiB  /    5.34 MiB  /    4.34 GiB  /   11.36 GiB
     yesterday    404.97 MiB  /     509 KiB  /  405.47 MiB
         today    593.05 MiB  /     773 KiB  /  593.80 MiB  /      --    

 enp59s0:
       Apr '18    206.79 GiB  /   56.90 GiB  /  263.69 GiB
       May '18     63.19 GiB  /   13.34 GiB  /   76.53 GiB  /  200.60 GiB
     yesterday      6.73 GiB  /  817.44 MiB  /    7.53 GiB
         today      4.03 GiB  /  376.32 MiB  /    4.39 GiB  /    5.31 GiB
```

Today the WiFi (wlp60s0) has sent/received 593 MB and Ethernet (enp59s0) has sent/received 4.39 GB.

To setup `vnstat` see this Q&A: [How to track the total network data in a month](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15836/how-to-track-the-total-network-data-in-a-month/844317#844317)

---

You don't have to tell Ubuntu to use Ethernet over Wifi because it automatically uses the fastest connection. The exception being if your Ethernet is 100 Mbps and your WiFi is faster than 300 Mbps. In this case the WiFi would take precedence.

If your WiFi is faster than your Ethernet click the Up/Down arrow representing network connection in the Systray. From the drop down menu disable the WiFi link by clicking `disconnect` button. You can also disable the Ethernet link from the same drop down menu.

Answer (score 2):

## With Pre-installed Tools

Check which **interfaces** are **connected**, and which are not:

```
$ sudo lshw -c network | egrep 'description|name|link'
```

Interface is **connected if** `link=yes`

**Monitor** the **traffic** on connected interfaces:

```
$ watch ip -s link
```

Look for interface names, after 1: 2: 3: etc. Ignore `lo` as this is loopback interface ([What is loopback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it))